# How can one incorporate an incomplete experiment into standard deviation?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, dataset

Let's say that I am an inspector working on an assembly line. I examine and pick out defective items so that they aren't put on the market.

Let's say that over a five week period, I note the number of defective items per week in the matrix A.

$$
A = [\begin{matrix}
12 \
14 \
13 \
11 \
13 ]\
\end{matrix}
$$

Let's assume that I know that the behaviour of the machine used to manufacture the items does not change over this time period so that all of these weeks and upcoming future weeks can be reasonably compared with one another. Also, the rate at which the machine is producing items remains constant, so an increase in the number of defects is not due to the fact that more items were made that week, nor is the reverse true when the number of defects decreases. I am interested in trying to estimate the mean and standard deviation of the failures. I could simply take the mean (12.6) and the standard deviation (~1.02) of the data in the matrix A.

However, let's say that we are 5 full days into the sixth week, and I have noted that 10 products have been defective so far. Is there some way that I can incorporate my incomplete data from this week to try to get a better estimate of the mean and standard deviation?

I believe that it is clear that observing more and more weeks worth of data is likely to improve the estimate of defective products, however I am unsure as to how to deal with incomplete data. Is it even valid to include it or should it be disregarded until a complete set of data has been formed for the week?

What proceeds this is how I would imagine incorporating the 5 latest days worth of data would look like but I would very much appreciate getting the opinions of others.

$$Since \ we\ have\ 5\ new\ days,\ that\ is\ \frac{5}{7}\ weeks,\ giving\ \frac{40}{7}\ weeks\ in\ total.$$

$$This\ means\ that\ the\ new\ mean\ is\ as\ follows$$

$$m = (\frac{12+14+13+11+13+10}{(\frac{40}{7})})=12.775$$

The standard deviation is calculated similarly to how it is normally, but the 10 defective products would not be compared to the calculated mean but rather the equivalent mean after 5 days, which is about 9.125.

$$σ\, =\, \sqrt\frac{(12-12.775)^2\,+\,(14-12.775)^2\,+\,(13-12.775)^2\,+\,(11-12.775)^2\,+\,(13-12.775)^2\,+\,(10-9.125)^2}{(\frac{40}{7})}\,≈\;1.03 $$

So it appears that this new piece of data increases both the mean and the standard deviation, since if defective products continue at the same rate, there will be 14 defective products this week, which is above the mean of the first 5 weeks. However, since there is no guarantee that 14 products will be defective this week (nor would it be expected to be based off of present data), the calculated mean and standard deviation would be less than assuming six full weeks with exactly 14 defects.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: My experience with industrial processes--even automated ones--is that they work a little differently on some days compared to others.  (You never have exactly the same people monitoring and maintaining them every day.)  Your implicit assumption that the process works the same every day therefore is questionable.  Without that assumption, there's not much you can do with partial-week information, unless it happens to be unusually large (thereby placing a lower bound on the possible value for the entire week), and even then your options are limited.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Perhaps I should have worded my assumption differently. Essentially, as a simplification I would like to assume that the machine will behave similarly enough on a day to day basis.

I am most interested in how a partial week analysis would be done and I appreciate the help and input.

Comment: The superior thing is to get day-specific information from the previous weeks' data. What you probably want is some type of control chart to identify normal operating ranges for defect-rates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does the standard deviation scale up if I just compared day to day? Getting the standard deviation of the 40 days is simple enough if that information is known. I can see how multiplying the day defective mean by 7 would give the same result as the weekly mean, but I don't understand how that would work for σ, since some days may have higher or lower than average numbers of defects, but taken blanketly over a longer time period, like a week or more, these numbers would likely get less unusual.

For that reason, how could I use day to day data to get a weekly estimate?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the rate of weekly defects comprises independent daily defects, you can provide a projection and uncertainty interval for the remainder of defects that would be generated by the current weekly process. The important thing is not to use mean imputation because it is too precise. Any process is bound to occasionally exceed the ranges of normal, and the fact that you are interested in observing the process only because of this signal greatly increases the chance of false positive findings. Multiply imputing the number of defects for the remainder involves generating data from a count process that roughly models extant defects. A Poisson or negative binomial model may be good. Historical data should provide some context, mainly for identifying the probability model for defects. Estimating the actual rate of defects for the probability model can be done using normal ranges or the abnormal ranges for the current week. By simulating the remainder of defects, one can generate bounds for the final weekly count of defects and compare them to normal ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this issue would be best represented as Poisson as you said. But, I am very interested in comparing the two models to see how the estimates compare & how they differ. I deemed it sensible to calculate λ as 12.775 defects/week. So, I can model the problem as Poisson since I have the shaping parameter λ.

I want to see how this would be represented as Gaussian, so I need x̅ & σ. I see that normal distribution is not appropriate here, but I am interested in if it is ever permissible to incorporate a partial statistic into σ, and if so, is it like how I suggested?